# ¿Cómo guardar logs en un archivo de texto plano?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, eventos

Me encuentro implementando un servicio de Windows en C# por medio del Visual Studio, y debido a que mi usuario no tiene los permisos de escritura correspondientes para registrar los logs en el visor de eventos de Windows, mi idea es crear un archivo de texto plano que contenga dichos logs, y que cada vez que ocurra un evento, le agregue una línea a dicho archivo con el log correspondiente y la hora y fecha del mismo. (Esto sería para evitar crear un nuevo archivo cada vez que ocurra un evento).
¿Alguna sugerencia sobre cómo hacer esto de la manera más segura y eficaz? O si se les ocurre alguna idea mejor, será bienvenida! Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: No has pensado en usar alguna librería con ese propósito? véase [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/) o [Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más sencillo es que te crees una clase que te gestione el tratamiento del archivo de log (por ejemplo generando uno por mes, borrando el más antiguo y renombrando el del mes anterior) y que por otro lado te realice la escritura en el archivo.

Te proporciono una clase que tengo montada para tal efecto y que hice para gestionar los logs de un servicio windows en el que tenía la misma problemática que tú:

```
class LogController
{
    public static void tratarFicheroLog()
    {
        try
        {
            string sLogComprueba1MesAnt = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogPath"] + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFileName"] + DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyyMM") + ".txt";
            string sLogComprueba2MesAnt = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogPath"] + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFileName"] + DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-2).ToString("yyyyMM") + ".txt";

            if (File.Exists(sLogComprueba2MesAnt))
                File.Delete(sLogComprueba2MesAnt);

            if (!File.Exists(sLogComprueba1MesAnt))
                File.Move(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogPath"] + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFileName"] + ".txt", sLogComprueba1MesAnt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    public static void WriteLog(string message)
    {
        string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogPath"] + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFileName"] + ".txt";
        StreamWriter stream = null;
        try
        {
            stream = File.AppendText(path);
            stream.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}.", DateTime.Now, message));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

El método `LogController` lo único que hace es comprobar si existe el fichero correspondiente a dos meses anteriores. Si existe lo elimina. Si quieres guardar este archivo, solo tendrías que renombrarlo. Lo siguiente que hace es ver si existe un archivo que se llame como se va a llamar el fichero de log. Si existe, renombra ese archivo al correspondiente al del mes anterior.

El método `WriteLog` lo único que hace es ir a buscar el archivo de log de forma que si no existe lo crea e inserta el `Datetime.Now` y el mensaje pasado por parámetro.

Esta clase tira de dos parámetros del fichero de configuración que tendrás que definir: `LogPath` para indicar la ruta donde va a estar el fichero y `LogFileName` que será como se llame el archivo sin la extensión.

En las excepciones o en los puntos donde quieras que se escriba en el log, pones esto:

```
        LogController.WriteLog(ex.Message);
```

Si quieres que cada mes se genere un nuevo archivo tienes que meter en la ejecución del `timer_elapsed`, antes de la ejecución de tu código esto:

```
        if(DateTime.Now.Day == 1)
        {
            LogController.tratarFicheroLog();
        }
```

Espero que sea lo que necesitas, cualquier duda me comentas.

**EDIT tras tu comentario**

En el fichero `app.config`, dentro de la sección `appSettings` defines las variables de esta manera:

```
<appSettings>
    <!-- Ruta donde se coloca el fichero de log  -->
    <add key="LogPath" value="D:\RutaLog\" />
    <add key="LogFileName" value="NombreLog" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta! Muchísimas gracias! Aun así estoy medio perdida en cuanto a cómo debería definir LogPath y LogFileName... los debería definir en dos variables nuevas, o directamente reemplazo dichos parámetros en el código que me brindaste?

Comment: Te he actualizado la respuesta con lo que tendrías que poner en el App.Config

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la excelente predisposición, me re sirvió tu ayuda!

Comment: Te agradecería entonces que marcaras mi respuesta como válida. ¡Me alegra que te sirviera!

Answer (score 0):

Si creas un `servicio de windows` los permisos del usuario no deberian afectar ya este ejecutan impersonando con el usuario que definas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si cambias a un usuario que tenga permisos de escritura en el log de windows deberia poder generar una entrada en el log de windows

Comment: Entiendo, pero se trata de un servicio que va a estar en un servidor que no es propio, por lo tanto ni siquiera haciendo esto podría asignarle permisos de escritura a mi usuario... de hecho lo intenté y no hubo caso

Comment: el servidor no es propio, pero tampoco tienes ningun contacto con la persona que lo administra para poder indicarle que configure correctamente los permiso ?

Comment: sino tienes permisos al log de windows, nada te asegura que tengas permiso de escritura a una carpeta para generar un archivo

Comment: Correcto, debido a que me contacté con el administrador y él mismo fue quien me denegó los permisos, es que estoy buscando la manera de evitar la escritura de logs. Para todo el resto puedo operar tranquilamente, los archivos los puedo crear de forma correcta, etc. Lo único que no puedo hacer es escribir en el visor de eventos de Windows